# Installing Letsencrypt on Centos Multilib error

Tags: centos, lets-encrypt

I have been trying to install lets encrypt on my cent os server running centos webpanel but have come in to the error

```html
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for openssl which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of openssl of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude openssl.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of openssl installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those arcitectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of openssl installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6_7.4.x86_64 != openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6.           i686
Could not install additional dependencies. Aborting bootstrap!
```

I have tried searching everything but can not find what is causing this error. I hope you can help me, as I am not that experienced with Centos yet and would be very thankful for any help!

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried `yum update` first?